# Should Test Code be Separate from Source/Production Code

Tags: unit-testing

Even if we have a Makefile or something similar to separate the test code when shipping product.
In my opinion, they should be separate, but i am not entirely convinced as to WHY

Comment: Our test code lives in the projects with the code it tests. Our build process doesn't copy them to the deploy folder.  (C# projects, MSBuild, MSTest) Why would you want separation?

Comment: depends on the tools being used, but for C  and Python, and using Jenkins its just easier to manage plus we can use the code coverage and static analysis tools supported by Jenkins seemlessly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they should be separate (folders and preferably projects). Some reasons:

- GREP. Searching for a string in production source is easier.
- Code coverage. Imagine trying to specify which files to include for coverage.
- Different standards. You may want to run static analysis, etc. only on production code.
- Simplified makefiles/build scripts.

Modern IDEs will allow you to work on code from separate projects/folders as if they were adjacent.

The **worst** thing you can do is to include test and production code in the same **file** (with conditional compilation, different entry points, etc.). Not only can this confuse developers trying to read the code, you always run the risk of accidentally shipping test code.

Comment: well said , i am also reading up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns applied to testing code

Answer (score 5):

Since I had a chance to work with both approaches (*separated* and *with project code*), here's few tiny-things that were *getting in a way* to note (C#, Visual Studio, MsBuild).

#### *Same project* approach

- References/external libraries dependencies: unit testing and mocking frameworks usually come with few dependencies on it's own, combine that with libraries you need for actual project and list grows **very** quickly (and nobody likes huge lists, right?)
- Naming collisions: having class named `MyClass`, common approach is to name test class `MyClassTest` - this causes tiny annoyances when using navigation/naming completition tools (since there's bigger chance you'll have more than one result to chose from for quick navigation)
- overall feeling of ubiquitous mess

*Naming collisions* can actually get even more tiresome, considering how classes relating to similar functionality usually share prefix (eg. `ListManager` ... Converter, Formatter, Provider). Navigating between comprehensible number of items (usually 3-7) is not a problem - enter tests, enter long lists again.

#### *Separated* approach

- Projects number: you'll have to count the number of libraries you produce twice. Once for project code alone, another time for tests. When bigger projects are involved (200-300+ sub-projects/libraries) having that number **doubled** by test projects extends IDE startup time in a way you never want to experience

Of course, modern machines will mitigate *projects number* issue. Unless this really becomes a problem, I'd **always** go for separated projects approach - it's just *more neat and clean* and way easier to manage.

Comment: @TrueWill: makes me think navigation is actually more than *tiny annoyance*... especially when few classes share same prefix (which is fairly common). Talk about *quick* navigation between 14 types.

Answer (score 1):

In fully automated building and unit testing framework, you can essentially separate them out.

It makes more sense to fire up the automated unit tests after the nightly build is done. 
Keeping them separate makes it easier for maintenance purposes.