# best location to write a unit-test (java)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jvm

What is the difference between writing a unit test in the same class as the tested method or writing it in another class (of the same package or extern package)?
What are the advantages or disadvantages of these test-locations?

Comment: Similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9022547/343266).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not "right" answer for this question.

Writing in the same class:
Allows you to test private methods but mess up the code.

Writing in the same project:
Allows you to test internal methods/logics but mess up the project and extends your compilation time.

Writing externally:
Prevents you from testing project internal methods/classes but keeps the tests clean and external to your "production" coder.

Comment: There is rarely any need to test private methods directly.  If you can't test some functionality of a private method via the non-private methods, then the chances are that the functionality is redundant.  Besides, if you really need to do this, you can call a private method reflectively.

Comment: I agree that you can reflectively but you don't want to start figuring out which tests to change upon changing you private APIs. In addition, testing private methods is less common than testing higher visible ones but still it can take place sometimes. Anyway, writing the tests inside the tested class is not something most people will do.

Comment: Compilation time should not be a big concern. I believe that compiling the same amount of code should take approximately the same amount of time regardless of whether the code is in a single class or two. Moreover, if the test code is separated, you actually have the option not to compile it to save time.

Comment: Exactly what I mean. Put it in another project and avoid the compilation of your tests unless you'd like to run them.

Comment: *"... but you don't want to start figuring out which tests to change upon changing you private APIs."  Red herring.  If you are directly testing private methods, and you change their APIs', then you NEED to change your unit tests.  It doesn't matter whether the unit tests are embedded in the code, or are in separate classes and use explicit reflection or some other means to call the methods.

Comment: When you are using reflection you'll know you need to change the calls only when you run the tests. Again, I would never write the tests in the tested class, he asked for pros and cons.

Comment: Note: if your comment doesn't include an '@' followed by the username of the person you are answering to (like @LiorOhana), that person won't ever be notified about your comment.

Comment: You don't need to put it in another project, only in a different source directory. E.g. Maven can handle this setup by default.

Comment: The need to test private methods is rare by itself, and almost always implies a code smell, which should be fixed by refactoring the class under test. So the "pro" side is very weak and only applies very rarely. Thus IMHO, contrary to your statement, there is a right answer to this question in 99.9% of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you have your tests in separate class(es), you can

- **use a well known unit testing framework** which makes your life way easier - all the ones I know assume that you keep your tests separated from the tested code
- have as many test cases as you like (without making your production class huge and hard to manage - note that in a well managed project, there is about as much unit test code as production code, and probably a lot more public test methods than production API methods, which may eventually drive the API indexer of your IDE, and subsequently yourself, crazy...)
- **ship your production code without tests** - including your test dependencies too (noone likes to bundle a ton of 3rd party stuff used only for testing into the product deployment bundle, right?)
- change tests without touching the production code itself (this will make auditing and change control in your SCM a lot easier, as it will always be trivial to separate changes in production code/data from changes in tests)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is separate tests from the code they are validating. The reason is simple: you do not want to package tests with your application. Application should be clean. Tests should validate functionality from outside.

Tests often have additional dependencies (e.g. testing framework, mockup library etc).

Common practice is to put source code under `src/main/java` and tests under `src/tests/java`.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of writing in separated classes is that you can separate your tests from your code. For example with maven :
1. Build everything
2. Executes the classes including the `**/*Test*.java pattern`

I don't even know how you can unit test in the same class than your code...

Answer (score 0):

Test methods are there to test your code. Putting them in the tested class clutters the API of the class, and makes the bytecode and dependencies of the class larger than necessary.

If I want to use your Calculator class, I don't need the `testPlusWorks()` and `testMinusWorks()` test methods. I just need `plus()` and `minus()`. And if `testPlusWorks` depends on some class from the JUnit or Mockito library, I don't want these dependencies in the production environment: they're only useful when testing the class.

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to write unit tests in a different source folder altogether, but keep them in the same package as you can still access packaged(default) scoped methods and varialble.

1. This keeps your tests together for ease of navigation and sanity and
2. When you do a build, you can exclude the test classes in the
   jar/war/ear.