# Python script that contains its own unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a small python script and I want to add a handful of tests.

For a larger system I would have modules and separate tests from the system under test, but for this tiny thing I want to keep it all in one .py file. Then I can run:

```
> foo.py --test
```

to run the tests and

```
> foo.py
```

to run my script normally.

I got this far:

```
import unittest
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--test", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if (args.test):
        return unittest.main()

class TestBasicFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

But it fails because unittest.main() tries to parse the arguments to my script.

I am not picky about unit test framework. py test, nose, whatever is fine.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there are [reasons you might want to consider separating unittests from the code it is testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9022547/190597).

However, here is how you *could* do it:

```
import unittest
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--test", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    if args.test:
        sys.argv.remove('--test')
        return unittest.main(argv=sys.argv)

class TestBasicFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```